What is the tradeoff which makes high altitude training effective?
Intuitively (feel free to tell me if this premise is wrong), the reason humans don't all have maximally strong muscles at all times is that maintaining larger muscles is more expensive. That's why we have to work out to build muscle rather than it being the default.
Why isn't the cardiovascular benefit of high altitude training just the default state of humans? What's the cost of being in that state all the time?

It's a common misconception that evolution drives organisms to perfection. Selection pressure pretty much goes away once an organism is outbreeding its competitors. If you'll forgive the anthropomorphism, nature is searching for "good enough" not perfect.

Your premise is wrong. My muscles are not as developed as those of a manual worker because I have a sedentary occupation. A road digger who works overtime will likely have more highly developed muscles than one who doesn’t. Development of arm and leg muscles will differ with occupation. Use seems to be what determines what percentage of “maximal capacity” is reached. Given the premise of your question is wrong I suggest you withdraw it.

How can a “benefit” be a “state”? Please read what you have written before posting.

You would experience unending High-altitude de-acclimatization syndrome aka, HADAS
symptoms include: headaches, insomnia or excessive somnolence, lower limb edema, diminished reflexes,  memory loss, inadequate fine motor coordination  blood clots, heart attack and stroke
most of this is due to changes in blood chemistry and thickness of the blood which increases blood pressure. It can even lead to direct cellular damage from persistant increased oxygen levels.
https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation?paperid=51517
enter link description here
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0006291X24003061
